# How to get running total for each quarter and instead of duplicate value to have 0. Using SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I need to calculate running total premium for each quarter.  But my data is broken down by date.

So I need the first row display value based on year and quarter, but if following rows have same `Year` and `Quarter`, then value should be 0.

This is what it looks like now:

[image]

But I need it like this:

[image]

Query with dummy data:

```
declare @TempTable1 table (ID int, Date date, PolicyNumber varchar(100), Premium money)

insert into @TempTable1 
values (1, '2018-01-01', 'Policy1', 100),
       (2, '2018-02-08', 'Policy2', 200),
       (3, '2018-04-15', 'Policy3', 300),
       (4, '2018-05-31', 'Policy4', 150),
       (5, '2018-07-10', 'Policy5', 250),
       (6, '2018-11-23', 'Policy6', 350),
       (7, '2018-12-05', 'Policy7', 330),
       (8, '2019-01-09', 'Policy8', 140),
       (9, '2019-06-18', 'Policy9', 225),
       (10, '2019-06-28', 'Policy10', 145)

SELECT  
    ID, 
    Date, 
    PolicyNumber,    
    YEAR(date) AS Year, 
    DATEPART(qq, date) AS Quarter,
    Premium,
    SUM(premium) OVER (ORDER BY YEAR(date), DATEPART(qq, date)) AS RunningTotal
FROM
    @TempTable1
```

Is it possible to achieve that in same `SELECT` statement?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is add a check to see if the `Year`/`Quarter` is changing or not via the `lag()` window function.

```
select  ID, 
        Date, 
        PolicyNumber,    
        Year(date) as Year, 
        DATEPART(qq,date) as Quarter,
        Premium,
        case when lag(DATEPART(qq,date), 1, null) over (order by Year(date),DATEPART(qq,date)) - DATEPART(qq,date) = 0 then 0 else
        sum(premium) over (order by Year(date),DATEPART(qq,date)) end as RunningTotal
from @TempTable1
```

I would suggest wrapping the initial calculated columns in a subquery to cut down on the number of `datepart()` calcs involved, but either solution will work.

**Subquery Option:**

```
select a.ID
, a.Date
, a.PolicyNumber
, a.Year
, a.Quarter
, a.Premium
, case when lag(a.Quarter, 1, null) over (order by a.Year,a.Quarter) - a.Quarter = 0 then 0 else
            sum(a.premium) over (order by a.Year,a.Quarter) end as RunningTotal
from (
    select  ID, 
            Date, 
            PolicyNumber,    
            Year(date) as Year, 
            DATEPART(qq,date) as Quarter,
            Premium
    from @TempTable1
    ) as a
```

Comment: Thank you! Is any way to tweak this query a little and get just SUM without running Total and without grouping by?  Thank you

Comment: @Oleg You mind updating your question with a second desired output? I think it will help me understand exactly what you’re looking for.

Answer (score 2):

try this.  It creates a row_number for each year and quarter partition, and only allows a calculated value for row = 1

```
SELECT ID,
        Date,
        policynumber, 
        dq2.year,
        dq2.Quarter,
        premium,
        case when rn=1 then runningtotal else 0 end 'runningtotal' 
from
    (
        select *,row_number() OVER (partition by year,quarter order by policynumber) as RN FROM
        (
        select  ID, 
                Date, 
                PolicyNumber,    
                Year(date) as 'Year', 
                DATEPART(qq,date) as [Quarter],
                Premium,
                sum(premium) over (order by Year(date),DATEPART(qq,date)) as RunningTotal

        from @TempTable1
        ) DQ
    ) DQ2
```